# I want to put a rig on my joined object properly

Tags: rigging

I want to put rig on my joined object properly.
But I had an error.

First, I made 16 seperate cubes and joined them as one objects.
Second, I made a Amature and set parent to amature deform with automatic weights
Last, when I move the Amature in pose mode, the object is twisted like the picture.

Is there any way to solve this error?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the mesh, go to edit mode, select all vertices of a block, use the buttons assign and remove to assign weight to the desired vertex group and remove from the others.

[image]

Comment: I don't get it /;

Comment: Select all vertices of the center "tower", select the vertex group with the same name as the center bone, click the assign button, select the left vertex group, click remove, select the right vertex group, click remove. Do the same with the others two "towers".

Comment: Thank you. I did it. But what if there is more than one bone, which bone should I assign to?

Comment: Center to the center bone (and remove from left and from right). Left to the left bone (and remove from center and from right). Right to the right bone (and remove from center and from left).